# update panel in asp.net causing full post back

Tags: asp.net, ajax

i've asp.net web application, i want to include ajax feature, i've added update panel script manager everything properly, but it still causing full post back,
do i need to do anything extra to include ajax in the existing project so that it should do partial post back

what can be the possible reasons for it to cause full post back,

iam using vissual studio 10 and my project targets .NET 4.0

What I have tried:

i've tried to include async postback trigger and defined trigger for controls and events, making update panel update mode attribute to conditional and children trigger attribute to false and for script manager set enable partial rendering to true
nothing working

```
enter code here<asp:scriptmanager ID="script1" runat="server"></asp:scriptmanager>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                    <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                        <tr>
                        <TD width=10><IMG height=1 src="../images/spacer.gif" width=10 border=0></TD>
                            <td  align="left">
                                <table class="titleTable" width="100%" cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <%--<td><A onclick="javascr:showHide('ExpiredItemsSection', 'ExpiredsearchImage');" href="javascri:void(0);"><STRONG>Expired Items</strong></A></td>
                                        <td align="right"><a href="javascri:void(0);" onclick="javascri:showHide('ExpiredItemsSection', 'ExpiredsearchImage');"><IMG id="ExpiredsearchImage" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="18" height="15" border="0" runat="server"></a></td>
                                    --%>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:linkbutton id="Expireditem" runat="server" onClick="Expireditem_Click">Expired Items</asp:linkbutton>
                                    </td>

                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                            <TD width=10><IMG height=1 src="../images/spacer.gif" width=10 border=0></TD>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"><IMG height=3 src="../images/spacer.gif" width=1 border=0></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>


                    <div id="ExpiredItemsSection" runat="server">
                        <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"><IMG height=10 src="../images/spacer.gif" width=1 border=0></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td width="10"><IMG height="1" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="5" border="0"></td>
                        <td noWrap align="center">
                            <table  cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0"  border="0" class="formTable" width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="right" height="20px"><strong><asp:label id="ExpiredItemsRenderNav" Runat="server" CssClass="blueText"></asp:label></strong>&nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                            <td width="10"><IMG height="1" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="5" border="0"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <TABLE cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="0" width="100%" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="3"><IMG height=3 src="../images/spacer.gif" width=1 border=0></td>
                        </tr>
                            <TR>
                                <TD width=10><IMG height="1" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="10" border="0"></TD>
                                <TD>
                                    <asp:datagrid id="ExpiredItemsList" runat="server" CssClass="dataTable" HorizontalAlign="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="False" PageSize="6" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" Width="100%" ToolTip="Click the items to view details" border="0">
                                        <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="grey"></AlternatingItemStyle>
                                        <ItemStyle CssClass="Right"></ItemStyle>
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="header" HorizontalAlign="left" />
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="ItemID" HeaderText="Item ID">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lblItemID" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval ( Container.DataItem, "ItemID" ) %>'>
                                                    </asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                            <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="Description" HeaderText="Description">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <IRIS:RBACLINK id="rbacDescription" NavigateURL="../MyIris/ViewItem.aspx" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval ( Container.DataItem, "Description" )%>' >
                                                    </IRIS:RBACLINK>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                            <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="lotno" HeaderText="Lot No">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="lotno" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval ( Container.DataItem, "lotno" ) %>'>
                                                    </asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                            <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="Serial No" HeaderText="Serial No">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Serial_No" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval ( Container.DataItem, "Serial No" ) %>'>
                                                    </asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                            <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="Ref Price" HeaderText="Value">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Ref_Price" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval ( Container.DataItem, "Ref Price" ) %>'>
                                                    </asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                            <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="Item Status" HeaderText="Item Status">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Item_Status" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval ( Container.DataItem, "Item Status" ) %>'>
                                                    </asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                            <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="location" HeaderText="Location">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="location" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval ( Container.DataItem, "location" ) %>'>
                                                    </asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                            <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="forecastdays" HeaderText="Days">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="forecastdays" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval ( Container.DataItem, "forecastdays" ) %>'>
                                                    </asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                            <asp:TemplateColumn SortExpression="expirydate" HeaderText="Expired Date">
                                                <ItemTemplate>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="ExpiryDate" Runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval ( Container.DataItem, "expirydate") %>'>
                                                    </asp:Label>
                                                </ItemTemplate>
                                            </asp:TemplateColumn>
                                        </Columns>
                                        <PagerStyle NextPageText="Next&#160;&lt;img src='../images/arrowsOutline.gif' border=0 alt='arrow Bullet' width='14' height='11' align='absmiddle'&gt;"
                                            PrevPageText="&lt;img src='../images/arrowsOutline_left.gif' border=0 alt='left Arrow' width='14' height='11' align='absmiddle'&gt;&#160;Previous"
                                            HorizontalAlign="Right"></PagerStyle>
                                    </asp:datagrid></TD>
                                <TD width=10><IMG height="1" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="10" border="0"></TD>
                            </TR>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3"><IMG height="10" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="1" border=0></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><IMG height="1" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="1" border=0></td>
                                <td class="lineSeperator" height="1"><IMG height="1" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="1" border=0></td>
                                <td><IMG height="1" src="../images/spacer.gif" width="1" border=0></td>
                            </tr>
                        </TABLE>
                    </div>
                      </ContentTemplate>
                     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Can you please share the source code. Doesn't help if your not putitng up your issues clearly.

Answer (score 0):

If You are not binding data inside form use

```
<UpdatePanel>
 <ContentTemplate>
     your content
 </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
           <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="control_id" />
        </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

If you are binding data then use

```
<UpdatePanel>
     <ContentTemplate>
         your content
     </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
               <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="control_id" />
            </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Hope this will help you. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Did you already try to set the Update Panel's **ClientIDMode** to **Static**? I've been where you are a couple of days ago and this stopped the page from refreshing entirely.